# Dismiss View Controller Bad Access

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am getting a Bad Access error when I try to dismiss my view controller:
(This code is in a view controller named NewTaskViewController)

```
self.delegate?.newTask(name: taskName!, date:date!,image:self.image, location:self.location) //line 1
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) //line2
```

If I remove line 1 I do not get the error.

`self.delegate` is the view controller (ViewController) that presented this view controller (NewTaskViewController) that I am attempting to dismiss with line 2.

The `newTask:` method is saving the arguments with Core Data: (inside ViewController)

```
 guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }


    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext


    let entity =
        NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Task",
                                   in: managedContext)!

    let task = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                insertInto: managedContext)


    task.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "name")

do {
        try managedContext.save()
        tasks.append(task)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```

Any ideas on why I do not get the bad access error when I remove the newTask: method that saves with Core Data. Is it that the newTask: method does not finish executing before `self.dmismiss` is called? But I don't understand how this is possible unless it has something to do with the way Core Data saves? Any ideas?

EDIT:
The error occurs in ViewController on the line:

```
newTaskViewController.delegate = self
```

Which is before the line that presents the `newTaskViewController`. How is this possible that the bad access error happens on code that has already been executed?

Comment: On which line of code does the error occur? From your description of the problem the error should occur in the `newTask` method.

Comment: @JackG. Ok, I've added more information to the question. It actually happens in the view controller that presents the one I'm trying to dismiss. Right before I present it, which is odd because that line has long since been executed?

Comment: Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: @JackG. It seems now of course I cannot replicate the error despite me changing nothing. Is there anything that sticks out to you? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe some async execution in the code or some context that is not set properly.

Comment: You should add more code around the line you're having trouble with.  Perhaps this line of code is in a block of code getting executed again? i.e. `viewWillAppear`, so it's trying to access a View that you've just dismissed and deallocated.